# Swift 3 collectionView how to set spacing.

Tags: swift, swift3, collections, view

[image]

1. How do you center the 3 cells? Its to the left.
2. How do you set same spacing on all sides of each cell?
3. Second cell that says no results found. how would you make that centered and take up whole screen? Right now its cut off in the top left corner.

Comment: is this query Solved ? if yes, close the thread by accepting or posting the answer you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make use of collectionView flowLayout

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

//MARK:- Collection View Flow Layouts
extension HomeVC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{    
    //MARK: Setting size of cell
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: width/3-16, height: width/3-16)
    }

    //MARK: Setting space Around Corners of Cells
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)
    }

    //MARK: Setting space between two sections
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 0
    }

    //MARK: Setting Space between two Cels
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 8
    }
}
```

StoryBoard Design

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this:

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width/3.05, height: width/3.05)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 1, bottom: 2, right: 1)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView.reloadData()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope this helps.